# Foreach реализация функций php

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

Доброго времени суток, если имеется массив

```
$trianglearray = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    $trianglearray [] = $triangle;
}
```

Мне необходимо воспроизвести функции для всех элементов в массиве, учитывая то что при каждом вызове в указаных элементах рандомно меняются значения.

При выполнении

```
foreach ($trianglearray as $triangle)

    {

       echo $triangle->Perimeter();
       echo "-Периметр треугольника <br/>";

       if ($triangle->isExist() == 1)
       {
           echo "Треугольник существует <br/>";
       }

       if ($triangle->isRectangular() == 1)
       {
           echo "Треугольник прямоугольный <br/>";
       }

       if ($triangle->isIsosceles() == 1)
       {
           echo "Треугольник равнобедренный <br/>";
       }

    }
```

Получаем

```
24-Периметр треугольника 
Треугольник существует 
Треугольник равнобедренный 
24-Периметр треугольника 
Треугольник существует 
Треугольник равнобедренный 
24-Периметр треугольника 
Треугольник существует 
Треугольник равнобедренный 
24-Периметр треугольника 
Треугольник существует 
Треугольник равнобедренный 
24-Периметр треугольника 
Треугольник существует 
Треугольник равнобедренный 
24-Периметр треугольника 
Треугольник существует 
Треугольник равнобедренный 
24-Периметр треугольника 
Треугольник существует 
Треугольник равнобедренный 
24-Периметр треугольника 
Треугольник существует 
Треугольник равнобедренный 
24-Периметр треугольника 
Треугольник существует 
Треугольник равнобедренный 
24-Периметр треугольника 
Треугольник существует 
Треугольник равнобедренный
```

Как сделать что бы выходили для каждого треугольника в массиве разные значения, а не 10 раз для одного и того же треугольника?

Comment: Как я понимаю, вы в каждый элемент массива складываете одну и ту же переменную $trianglearray [] = $triangle. У вас получается массив из одинаковых значений. Складывайте в массив разные значения, тогда и результаты функций будут (скорее всего :) ) разными.

Comment: `for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
    $trianglearray [] = new Triangle(ДАННЫЕ_КОНСТРУКТОРА);
}`

Comment: Спасибо тебе мил человек, как поблагодарить?)